# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

Whenever I try to add a FloatingActionButton to my app, I get an InflateException.
Here is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="wtw.sunonetaji.landing.MainScreenListActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_screen_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="wtw.sunonetaji.landing.MainScreenListActivity">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bgcoloor"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pencileditbutton"
        app:borderWidth="1dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my exception:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="wtw.sunonetaji.landing.MainScreenListActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_screen_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="wtw.sunonetaji.landing.MainScreenListActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/bgcoloor"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pencileditbutton"
    app:borderWidth="1dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add **Design Support Library** in **gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```